# [swift5][ios] How can I open DatePicker by a button Click?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker

I want to make such that if I click a button, it should show DatePicker
If I select day from DatePicker, display label or textfield
How can I hide or no create DatePicker on storyboard

I have been searching many times and find many example code
but those example code display datepicker initially
sorry, my english so bad, I`m korean

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVMO7.png)

```
     @IBAction func changeDatePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
     }



 }
 extension UITextField{
     func setDatePicker(target: Any, selector: Selector){
         let SCwidth = self.bounds.width
         let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 
         SCwidth, height: 216))
         datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
         //self.inputView = datePicker
    
         let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x:0.0, y: 0.0, width: SCwidth, 
         height: 44.0))
         let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, 
         target: nil, action:nil)
         let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, 
         target:nil, action: #selector(tapCancel))
    
         let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, 
         target: 
         target, action: selector)
         toolBar.setItems([cancel, flexible, barButton], animated: false)
         //self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
     }
     @objc func tapCancel(){
         self.resignFirstResponder()
     }
}
```

Comment: Show a view controller when a button is tapped with `popoverPresentationController`.

Comment: Do you want the date picker to appear inline where the button is too, or should it appear in a new view on top of the view where the button is?